# Updating Realm Object With Primary Key (Swift)

Tags: swift, realm, primary-key

I'm trying to update/add to Realm database using primary key. I use this code snippet from Realm documentation:

```
var person = ["personID": "My-Primary-Key", "name": "Tom Anglade"]

// Update `person` if it already exists, add it if not.
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true)
}
```

But when I try to implement it, it returns this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[String : String]' to expected argument type 'Object'
```

I'm kind of stuck here so any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using does not support update with Dictionary, I think you were trying to use  `create(_:value:update:)` version.

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.create(Person.self, value: person, update: true) // here person is dictionary with attributes for updating person
}
```

You could also use the `add(_:update:)` method, but it requires that you pass **Realm** `Object` to it.

```
let person = Person()
person.name = dict["name"]
... 
let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(person, update: true) // here person is Object of type Person 
}
```

[Here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes) is the official Realm documentation.

Comment: The first method worked perfectly. What's confusing (at least to me) is that Realm describes it differently on this page: https://academy.realm.io/posts/realm-primary-keys-tutorial/ But hey, now it works, so thank you!

Comment: 'add(_:update:)' is deprecated: Pass .error, .modified or .all rather than a boolean. .error is equivalent to false and .all is equivalent to true.